# SLRequest Twitter iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, twitter, slrequest

I am downloading a users timeline for my iOS app. Right now I am getting the full JSON response from Twitter's API URL https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json

It is returning everything as shown here...

```
Timeline response: (
            {
            contributors = "<null>";
            coordinates = "<null>";
            "created_at" = "Sat Jun 08 03:59:36 +0000 2013";
            entities =         {
                hashtags =             (
                );
                symbols =             (
                );
                urls =             (
                                    {
                        "display_url" = "vine.co/v/bLrw1IjLKVl";
                        "expanded_url" = "https://vine.co/v/bLrw1IjLKVl";
                        indices =                     (
                            36,
                            59
                        );
                        url = "https://t.co/8yHzCzMFHC";
                    }
                );
                "user_mentions" =             (
                );
            };
            "favorite_count" = 3;
            favorited = 0;
            geo = "<null>";
            id = 343215709989507073;
            "id_str" = 343215709989507073;
            "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
            "in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
            "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
            "in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
            "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
            lang = en;
            place = "<null>";
            "possibly_sensitive" = 0;
            "retweet_count" = 1;
            retweeted = 0;
            source = "<a href=\"http://vine.co\" rel=\"nofollow\">Vine - Make a Scene</a>";
            text = "Black people neighborhoods at night https://t.co/8yHzCzMFHC";
            truncated = 0;
            user =         {
                id = 1129039734;
                "id_str" = 1129039734;
            };
        }
    )
```

But I only want the "text" parameter. How do I only get the text of the tweets?

Thanks!

-Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up using...

```
NSDictionary *timelineData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
                            if (timelineData) {
                                tweets = [NSMutableArray new];
                                for (NSDictionary * obj in timelineData) {
                                    NSString *text = [obj objectForKey:@"text"];
                                    [tweets addObject:text];
                                }
                                [self updateTableView];
                            }
```

Hopefully this helps a few people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a JSON Parser that parses out what you need and discards the rest, for example [yajl](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc). There are plenty of examples. Yajl is fast...

The ugly solution would be to use the NSString message: componentsSeparatedByString to split the NSString containing your json on "text = " and then on "truncated = " to get the text in between...

Using NSJSONSerialization, there is an excellent example  for twitter [here](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/03/06/parsing-json-in-objective-c-using-nsjsonserialization/)

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
  URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?
  screen_name=xx"]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
  returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
  options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSDictionary *tweet;
for(int i=0; i<[publicTimeline count];i++)
{
    tweet= [publicTimeline objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@”Statuses: %@”, [tweet objectForKey:@"text"]);
}
```

Comment: Well actually iOS now has a built in API JSON parser so this would not be the best way.

Comment: @Henry: You are correct, JSON support is now native to iOS with NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: So then how would I go about parsing all these "tweets" for just the text value?